# G1 - two consecutive full garbage collections occurs periodically

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-7

I am using G1 garbage collector, under Java 7 update 45 with 1g heap on CentOS 6 64 bits.
I see periodically that two full garbage collections occurs right one after the other while the first one clean very small amount of memory and the second one clean reasonable amount.

Example from my gc log:

[image: consecutive full garbage collections]

After 25 minutes this happens again:

[image: consecutive full garbage collections]

Any idea what can lead to this behaviour? Why the memory isn't cleared during the first full gc?

I tried to run my webapp with latest java 7 (update 67), this phenomenon happens again.

[image: consecutive full garbage collections]

If I understand right the gc log then from the following young gc the heap size increased in 18.8M, so a assume that the allocation failure that caused to full gc bound by this value. Eventhough more empty space is available on the heap, why G1 trigger full gc? From the attached graph can be seen that the heap size never grows than 900M, why?

[image: Heap size graph]

Comment: I suggest, use the latest update as this might be behaviour they have fixed.  A 1 GB heap is pretty small these days, I would try increasing it to see if it behaves better. A vague rule of thumb is 3-5x the memory used after a full collection. I usually start at 32  GB and work my way down if that appears to be a waste.

Comment: Unfortunately the heap size is limited in this configuration. In my other configurations with heap size is 1.5g I see much better results.

Comment: Two GCs in a row is required to reclaim "weak" references.  Presumably your app has a lot of cached storage using weak references, and that must be reclaimed to achieve a reasonably "clean" heap.

Comment: I thought that this maybe the reason but barely found such caches. In addition if I run manual gc couple times this not happens.

Comment: Reclaiming "weak" references only happens when GC decides it should happen, using heavens knows what metric.  (The implementation of weak references is rather badly bungled in Java.)